# How do you sync 1 world between Switch and PC on Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to be able to go out and play my world and continue to play it at home on my pc, is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You have to get a realm to do that.

Even if you're just transferring a world between platforms, Microsoft's guide for it requires a realm.

They're not that expensive. I pay about £3/mo for the one I use for my nephew and I regularly switch between mobile and XBox to play on it. The one downside is you *have to* use Wi-Fi to play a realm on mobile so you can't play on the go.

## Edit 1

Actually, there is the free option of leaving one device running at all times. If you create a second account and add yourself as a friend you could leave the PC one on and then join it when you're on the switch. Would mean managing two Steves, though.